# Big files take unjustly long time to submit from the form Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, forms, wamp

I am creating a project using Laravel PHP, which requires selecting a video file from form and submitting it to controller function for further processing. But I came across this issue that those video files take a lot of time just to submit, e.g. 600MB video takes about 10-15 minutes just to reach the controller, and I am required to upload video files up to 3GB ...

Before writing this question I studied multiple threads on different forums and came across the solutions where it would be required to increase values of `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` & `memory_limit`, so I did that. With the help of `phpinfo()` I found out that in my Laravel project has "Loaded Configuration File" from `D:\wamp\bin\php\php8.1.10\php.ini`. So I opened the file and changed all the aforementioned fields to 3000M:

```
post_max_size = 3000M
upload_max_filesize = 3000M
memory_limit = 3000M
```

I made sure that those settings applied by checking in `phpinfo()`.

Here's the config: [phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQP0h.png)

But this did not fix the issue, file submission still takes an unjustly long time.

web.php

```
Route::post('/add-video', [App\Http\Controllers\VideosController::class, 'createVideo'])->name('createVideo');
```

Form:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'createVideo', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'videoForm', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) }}
  {{ Form::file('video'); }}
  {{ Form::submit('Add Video') }}                                
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller function (basically does nothing at this point, since the problem is with file submission and NOT with processing logic):

```
public function createVideo(Request $request)
{
    var_dump($request->video);
}
```

Would also like to note that the same action in a simple WAMP project (with the same `php.ini` config), would usually take not more than 5 seconds. Both projects would run on the same hardware, with the same configuration, the only difference is that one of them is based on Laravel ...

Comment: Those limits you are setting exist to prevent big uploads, not to slow them down. As far as I know, PHP does not provide any builtin mechanism to throttle incoming requests.

Comment: The PHP settings you have changed are, as their names suggest, related to the size of the upload, and have nothing to do with upload speed.  I don't think there are any PHP settings that would change upload speed.  "*the same action in a simple WAMP project ... would usually take not more than 5 seconds*" - I am not sure but it sounds like you are speculating here, I mean are you saying you have, recently, as part of your debugging, actually timed the upload from the same origin to the same target, outside Laravel?

Comment: Eg copy-paste the rendered HTML of your view above to a new page where Laravel will not handle it (eg`/public/form.php`), update the form target to POST to itself and include `print_r($_POST);` at the top.

Comment: well using `var_dump` to output might be the thing that slows the process down a lot ;-)

Comment: A difference of "about 10-15 minutes" with Laravel vs. "not more than 5 seconds" when using "plain" PHP, indeed seems a bit unrealistic. I'd start by doing some actual measuring here - take the current timestamp in your Laravel index.php, at the very start, and again when it finally enters into the controller method, and see what the difference is. That should help clarify, whether it is actually Laravel's additional processing of such a request, that costs you the majority of time here - or something else.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I indeed timed out the upload time of the same files, located on the same drive and in the same folder from Laravel Project & WAMP project.  With WAMP the entire process took 8:33 seconds, while Laravel project took its time with 5 minutes & 12 seconds (for 160MB video). I wouldn't even complain if it wasn't for a fact that WAMP with the same configuration does it like 30x times faster. And the bigger the video size the more notable is the time difference...

Comment: @CBroe Interestingly enough, the result indicated that the time taken for the request to be processed from the start of the index.php file to entering the controller method is approximately 0.0319 seconds, or around 31.92 milliseconds... But the overall loading process took about 5 minutes.

Comment: Would be interesting to know next, whether the majority of those five minutes are spent before the index.php gets invoked, or afterwards, in the controller method. Since laravel probably can't have too much influence on what happens before it starts, I would assume it is probably the latter. What laravel does to parse the request, to provide the `Request $request` for the controller to work with, probably takes time. Not sure if you could convince laravel to forgo its usual request parsing (and then work with $_POST / $_FILES directly) for one specific method somehow?

Comment: I tried it on the fresh laravel (v11) project and there was no issue. I just uploaded a 1 GB file and saved it on my storage which hardly took a minute in the local environment. You are sure that you don't have any middleware or service provider that is doing something before you reach the controller?

Comment: @AnujShrestha Nope, nothing but the default ones. Mine version is 10.46.0 and at this point I have no idea what kind of bug that is

Comment: I even created a fresh new Laravel project(breeze/blade/PHPUnit/sqlite) and the issue is there by default...